# Install cannot change permission of non existent file

Tags: permissions

I am doing cross linux from scratch and stumbled in a small mistake related to permissions.

At the stage 5.5 (Linux Header), the reader is supposed to issue a:

```
install -dv /tools/include
```

When I do so, I end receiving:

```
install: cannot change permissions of `/tools/include': No such file or directory
```

Both tools and its subdir belong to the clfs user and have writing permissions to its owner:

```
drwxr-xr-x  13 clfs     clfs      137 Oct 31  2012 tools

drwxr-xr-x  3 clfs clfs   18 Oct 31  2012 include
```

and I am logged as the owner:

```
clfs@leopoldo-desktop:/mnt/clfs/sources/linux-3.4.17$
```

So, I am open to suggestions.

Edited: Output of `ls -ld /tools`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Dec 25 11:37 /tools -> /mnt/clfs/tools/
```

Comment: Submit a fault report to the owner?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of the command `ls -ld /tools`

Comment: @SottoVoce. I added the output that you asked for.

Comment: You've been giving the install command a path that depends on a symbolic link.  Have you tried it with the real path?  I.e., `install -dv /mnt/clfs/tools/include` ?  Do you get a clearer error message?